# ¿Cómo pasar datos de una JTable hacia otra JTable? (Están en diferentes clases)

Tags: java, netbeans, objeto, jframe, jtable

Tengo una tabla en la clase Proveedores, la tabla es JTable y utilice el DefaultTableModel, la tabla contiene 4 columnas (Empresa, Producto, Cantidad, Precio), al momento de registrar datos si los guarda en un archivo de texto. Lo que quiero es que esos datos se vayan automaticamente a la tabla de Inventario que es una clase diferente (Clase Inventarios).
Todo lo estoy programando en Jva NetBeans 8.2

Comment: ¿Cuando construyes una tabla cómo lo haces? Puedes implementar un método en una clase que reciba como parámetro un arreglo o matriz con los datos de la otra clase. No es lo óptimo pero puede funcionar.

Comment: Debes adjuntar un [example] de lo que has intentado o como lo estas realizando en tu pregunta.